# Anyone managed to get Leaflet.Elevation working with react-leaflet?

Tags: node.js, npm, elevation, react-leaflet

I use npm package management and my package.json looks like this:

```
"leaflet": "1.0.3",
"leaflet.elevation": "0.0.3",
...
"react-leaflet": "1.1.4",
```

I thought to use [leaflet.elevation](https://github.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Elevation) in traditional (non-react) way, however `L.control.elevation` which is meant to be used as constructor is `undefined`.

I am able to use Leaflet via the global `L` variable and also via import as this this one:

```
import MyOwnLeaflet from 'leaflet';
MyOwnLeaflet.Marker
```

however when I try to use `leaflet.elevation` in the same manner:

```
import MyOwnLeafletElevation from 'leaflet.elevation';
```

I end up with:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet.elevation'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like leaflet.elevation is missing the main entry in it's package.json file, so that may explain the error.

Perhaps you could try the following:

```
import 'leaflet.elevation/dist/leaflet.elevation-0.0.4.min.js'
```

Comment: Thanks Evan, that worked -- though one has to actually call `import 'leaflet.elevation/dist/leaflet.elevation-0.0.2.min.js` when using leaflet.elevation 0.0.3. After then `L.control.elevation()` constructor works.

Comment: @Peter I trying to get leaflet.elevation work with react-leaflet as well, do you have a sample of how to initialise it in react-leaflet

Comment: @vitohuang, at the end we abandoned leaflet-elevation because it looks not very well maintaned and we build the elevation profile chart using chart.js. here is our [elevation chart react component](https://github.com/FreemapSlovakia/freemap-v3-react/blob/master/src/components/ElevationChart.js).

Comment: Nice one! it looks good and a lot easier to implement everything from scratch, I did managed to get it working for my app, but thinking to extend it and make it into a react-leaflet component to save people pain